# Map* vs MapMiddleware*

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

ASP.NET CORE MVC have methods for route mapping:

- MapGet
- MapDelete
- MapPost
- MapPut
- MapVerb

And with using middleware:

- MapMiddlewareGet
- MapMiddlewareDelete
- MapMiddlewarePost
- MapMiddlewarePut
- MapMiddlewareRoute
- MapMiddlewareVerb

Is there any difference? 
Visually they solve the same problems.

When is one used instead of the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the difference from the method signatures:

```
public static IRouteBuilder MapVerb(this IRouteBuilder builder,
    string verb, string template, RequestDelegate handler);

public static IRouteBuilder MapMiddlewareVerb(this IRouteBuilder builder,
    string verb, string template, Action<IApplicationBuilder> action);
```

[`MapVerb`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.requestdelegateroutebuilderextensions.mapverb?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is used to register a *request delegate* with a specific route. This allows you to run code directly on that route to produce a result. For example:

```
route.MapGet("/test", async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world");
});
```

[`MapMiddlewareVerb`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.requestdelegateroutebuilderextensions.mapmiddlewareverb?view=aspnetcore-3.1) on the other hand is used to register an *application builder pipeline*. This basically allows you to fork the middleware pipeline and execute middlewares on specific routes. This is similar to the [`MapWhen` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.mapwhenextensions.mapwhen?view=aspnetcore-3.1) that forks the middleware pipeline directly. But `MapMiddlewareVerb` uses endpoint routing to do that:

```
route.MapMiddlewareGet("/test", testApp =>
{
    testApp.UseStaticFiles();
    testApp.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleware>();
});
```

As for the other methods that have a specific verb, they are just shortcuts for `MapVerb(<verb>, …)` and `MapMiddlewareVerb(<verb>, …)`.